# Singleton: create instance inside static constructor

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I was reading about Singleton design pattern when i come across this implementation:

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton Instance { get; private set; }

    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    static Singleton()
    {
        Instance = new Singleton();
    }
}
```

Is this singleton thread safe? What are pros and cons of such implementation?

Comment: For discussion of pros/cons (which are mostly off-topic on Stack Overflow), see e.g. http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: I saw that article, but the above example was not mentioned

Comment: Your example is functionally identical to simply initializing the backing field directly, e.g. `static Singleton Instance { get; } = new Singleton();`, a variation that _is_ discussed in the article. Of course, the code you posted is useless, because the `Instance` property is `private`, and so can only be called by the `Singleton` class itself (which has no constraints on how many instances of `Singleton` it can create...singletons are really only useful constructs for outside code).

Answer (score 0):

No singletons are not thread safe, I would recommend reading https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: The singleton _initialization_ the OP is asking about _is_ thread-safe. Of course, whether the singleton _object_ itself is thread-safe is a completely separate matter. Though, it'd be very bad form to write a singleton object that isn't thread-safe in a context where thread-safety is in any way an issue, since by its very nature, a singleton is used repeatedly and potentially concurrently.